# How to caption text examples?

Tags: captions

I need to add a `\caption` to some textual examples. For example:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged

**Example 1.** Lorem Ipsum

However, what is caption type in such cases? There is obviously no `\captionof{example}{Lorem Ipsum}`. I could only find `\captionof{figure}` and `\captionof{table}` but this is pretty limiting.

Comment: Should this content float within the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create your own caption type if you wish to use a non-default `\caption`. [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) provides this functionality, as does [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfloat,caption,float}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext = loe,
  listname = Examples,
  name = Example,
  placement = H,
  within = none,
  ]{example}
\captionsetup[example]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

Some text before.

\begin{example}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the~1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

\caption{Lorem Ipsum}
\end{example}

Some text after.

\end{document}
```

While `example` is considered a *float*, the positioning is set to `[H]`ere by default and therefore will not float. It seems reasonable that the construction should not be broken across the page boundary, as it would not make sense otherwise.